# Tengo un error aunque tenga un try-except

Tags: python, utf-8, unicode

Estaba aburrido, así que hice una práctica para mantener mis conocimientos y habilidades de Python y otros lenguajes de programación. Decidí hacer un programa que modifique archivos, y en una opción de leer el contenido de un archivo, pensé en qué pasaría si intento leer un archivo .exe, .pdb o de otra terminación que no se pueda codificar en UTF-8. Para evitar este problema, usé un bloque de try-catch para que imprima que el archivo no se puede leer si sale ese error, pero me lanza el error mismo.

Código:

```
elif option.lower() == "d":
    print("\033c")
    file = input("Enter the file you want to view (specify path if needed): ")
    try:
        file = open(file, 'r')
    except FileNotFoundError or UnicodeDecodeError:
        print("\033cAn error occured, try again later")
        exit()
    text = file.read()
    print(f"\033c{text}")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\...\__main__.py", line 74, in <module>
    text = file.read()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 4096: invalid continuation byte
```

Aún con el bloque de try-except me sigue apareciendo el error, y ya intenté solo con el UnicodeDecodeError para ver si había algo en la línea del "except" pero no pasa nada, si necesitan más información me la pueden pedir, gracias.

Comment: Parece que tu `text = file.read( )` está fuera del `try`.

Comment: en el `try` solo abres el archivo pero la lectura esta fuera de este

Comment: el error está en que si es un exe lo que querés leer la propiedad de lectura es 'rb' y cabe aclarar que la lectura es en hexa y si el archivo es muy grande deberás leer por bloques.

Comment: Listo, ya cambié mi read(file, "r") a read(file, "rb")